# Batch File look through an entire file for "T/C" and type 480 chars after each "T/C" it Encounters

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I know this can be done easily with SQL Server but the funny thing is my work is not giving me access to SQL server so I don't know how else to do this other than through batch file or if it's even possible?

I have a flat file from a report that gets generated there's no row delimiters so it's just a bunch of rows with 1024 chars.  My goal is to find every occurrence of the words "T/C" and read 480 characters after that and it loops until it reaches the end of file. The best I can conjure up right now is this, I'm pretty clueless about batch files:

```
  for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (sample.txt) do (
  set line=%%a
  set chars=!line:~0,480!
  echo !chars! --- !line!
  )> text.txt
```

Comment: Is `T/C` on each line, and you want 480 characters after `T/C` from the same line?

Comment: It's one gigantic line, but since notepad can only handle 1,024/line it's broken into 66 "lines".

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "prevline="
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q19992107.txt) DO (
  SET line=%%a
  CALL :check
 )
 SET "line="
 CALL :check
)>newfile.txt
TYPE newfile.txt
GOTO :EOF

:check
IF NOT DEFINED prevline GOTO done
SET aftertc=%prevline:*T/C=%
IF "%aftertc%"=="%prevline%" SET prevline=%prevline:~-2%%line%&GOTO :eof
SET bothline=%prevline%%line%
SET aftertc=%bothline:*T/C=%
SET aftertc=%aftertc:~0,15%
ECHO %aftertc%
:done
SET prevline=%line%
GOTO :eof
```

Batch is not an ideal tool for this - but the above may do the trick.

essentially, it keeps two lines, `prevline` and `line`.
If the target string is NOT contained in the previous line, add the last 2 characters of the previous line to current line and use the result as previous.

Otherwise, concetenate the two lines, abd dispose of that pasrt that precedes the `T/C` Then lop off the tail - I restricted the tail to 15 chracters for testing convenience. Then use the current line as previous.

The reason for using the last 2 characters is to include the `T` or `T/` from the previous line if the `T/C` sequence is split over lines.

Here's the test file I used in `q19992107.txt`

```
this is skipped
this contains T/C in line
no contents
skip this
this is irrelevant
split on / in T/
C was 1 split
this is irrelevant
split on / in T
/C was 2 split
there IS T/C
at the end of the previous line
and then there is T/C in the last
```

And the results in `newfile.txt`

```
 in lineno cont
 was 1 splitthi
 was 2 splitthe
at the end of t
 in the last
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried it but it doesn't appear to be working.  Can you give some advice on troubleshooting?  The batch did generate the newfile.txt but there was nothing inside the newfile.txt

Comment: Remove the redirection to `newfile.txt` to make the output visible. Use the test data I've provided above to reduce the line length. Insert a `PAUSE` command just before the final `GOTO :EOF` to stop the report after each line is read. Comment-out the initial `@echo` to receive a report of each line as it is executed. You should be able to trace any problem from there.